# How to get a name of uploaded file from cleaned_data?

Tags: django, forms, file, python-3.x

I have this function for file handling:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f, person):
    with open(user_directory_path(person, f.name), 'w') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

And I call this function in form save method:

```
class CreateMessageForm(forms.Form):
    files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    ...
    def save(self):
        ...
        for file in cleaned_data.get('files'):
            handle_uploaded_file(file, self.person)
            message.files.add(file)
```

But after sending this form I have an AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'name'. I don't understand what's wrong. In the docs uploadedfile object has this attribute.

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form

Comment: @itzmeontv It was already added. Sorry, I might to write about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens:
When you run, `for file in self.cleaned_data["files"]:`, you are expecting it to iterate over a list of uploadedFile objects and pass each to the handler function. But `cleaned_data['files']` is not a list for you, it's just ONE single instance of uploadedfile. When you iterate over a file object, you're actually reading it. So what you pass eventually to the handler function is not the file object but its content (as a bytes string). Rewrite this part to check if it's a list before iterating. If it's a single file, pass it as it is.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your html form.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `FileField` in your form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

And in the view, do the following:

```
def upload(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.is_valid():
           form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
           file = form.cleaned_data.get('file')
           ...
```

Comment: I added the information about this field. When I transfer these operations in a view I have the same error.

Comment: you're missing `if form.is_valid():`, so cleaned_data is not available.